# Why does this implicit conversion from int to uint work?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

Using [Casting null doesn't compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008339/casting-null-doesnt-compile) as inspiration, and from Eric Lippert's comment:

> That demonstrates an interesting case. "uint x = (int)0;" would
>   succeed even though int is not implicitly convertible to uint.

We know this doesn't work, because `object` can't be assigned to `string`:

```
string x = (object)null;
```

But this does, although intuitively it shouldn't:

```
uint x = (int)0;
```

Why **does** the compiler allow this case, when `int` isn't implicitly convertible to `uint`?

Comment: I suppose the same reason `unit x = 0` works. `0` is a signed int unless you specify `unit x = 0U`.

Comment: Probably 6.1.9 of the spec and discounting of the int cast, because 0 is already an int. While generally an int is not implicitly convertible to uint (6.1.2), a *constant expression* of type int can be converted.

Comment: What value does `0` implicitly have as a constant expression then? Does the compiler just ignore the `(int)` explicit cast and treat `0` as a `uint` constant?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8419323/601179) Eric Lippert answer.

Comment: @Yuck, the compiler sees an `int` constant. However, it also knows that a non-negative `int` constant can safely be converted into a `uint`.

Comment: @Yuck It's not just `0`. Any numeric literal that is naturally an `int` and that fits in a `uint` will work here, and it certainly seems to be because the cast is elided.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does a compiler dislike implicitly casting to uint's?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860863/why-does-a-compiler-dislike-implicitly-casting-to-uints)

Comment: What a little stupid mistake I did at work cause... =) Poor Eric.

Comment: @gdoron I think they're both good questions. It's important for .NET developers (those using frameworks in general) to understand what their code is *really* doing.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Integer constant conversions are treated as very special by the C# language; here's section 6.1.9 of the specification:

> A constant expression of type int can be converted to type sbyte, byte, short, ushort, uint, or ulong, provided the value of the constant-expression is within the range of the destination type. A constant expression of type long can be converted to type ulong, provided the value of the constant expression is not negative.

This permits you to do things like:

```
byte x = 64;
```

which would otherwise require an ugly explicit conversion:

```
byte x = (byte)64; // gross
```

Comment: So in the case of `uint i = (int)0;`, the compiler just ignores the cast? Or is it just that the result of casting a constant expression is itself a constant expression?

Comment: @dlev: The latter. Casting a constant expression of type int to int is still a constant expression.

Comment: But isn't `(int)0` a variable\value and not a "constant expression"?

Comment: @gdoron nope it's not. The compiler will know the result at compile time.

Comment: @JonH: It is a reasonable question. The rule only applies if the expression is a *constant expression of type int* and the result is in the range. In this case, (int)0 *is* a constant expression. I note that we have made mistakes here in the past. For example, the spec says that *the literal zero* is implicitly convertible to any enum. But we also allow "E e = 0 + 0;" despite the fact that "0 + 0" is *not* "the literal zero" -- it is two literal zeros with a plus between them.

Comment: @gdoron: it is clearly not a *variable* because **a variable is by definition a storage location**. It is classified as a *value*; a *constant expression* is a particular kind of *value*.

Comment: One interesting point here is that an integer constant has indeed a certain type(`int`, `byte`) and isn't just an abstract "integer constant" type, which is important for type inference.

Comment: @CodeInChaos I don't think any numeric literals are of type `byte`. For integer literals I think the options are `int`, `uint`, `long` and `ulong`, based on the "smallest" type that can store the number.

Comment: With the enums the underlying design issue was reusing the literal `0` as default value of enums, instead of defining a new keyword such as `none`. Reminds me of how c treats `0` vs `null`, and how it was finally resolved using `nullptr` in C++11.

Comment: @dlev I'm talking about constants/constant expressions, not just literals.

Answer (score 9):

The following code wil fail with the message "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'uint'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

```
int y = 0;
uint x = (int)y;
```

And this will fail with: "Constant value '-1' cannot be converted to a 'uint'"

```
uint x = (int)-1;
```

So the only reason `uint x = (int)0;` works is because the compiler sees that 0 (or any other value > 0) is a compile time constant that can be converted into a `uint`

Comment: So basically it optimizes the cast away since it's not needed for a literal?

Comment: @BoltClock A constant expression can be converted at compile time so the cast is indeed removed.

Answer (score 2):

In general compilers have 4 steps in which the code is converted.
Text is tokenized > Tokens are parsed > An AST is built + linking > the AST is converted to the target language.

The evaluation of constants such as numbers and strings occurs as a first step and the compiler probably treats 0 as a valid token and ignores the cast.