# C# Method overload resolution not selecting concrete generic override

Tags: c#, generics, overload-resolution

This complete C# program illustrates the issue:

```
public abstract class Executor<T>
{
    public abstract void Execute(T item);
}

class StringExecutor : Executor<string>
{
    public void Execute(object item)
    {
        // why does this method call back into itself instead of binding
        // to the more specific "string" overload.
        this.Execute((string)item);
    }

    public override void Execute(string item) { }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object item = "value";
        new StringExecutor()
            // stack overflow
            .Execute(item); 
    }
}
```

I ran into a StackOverlowException that I traced back to this call pattern where I was trying to forward calls to a more specific overload. To my surprise, the invocation was not selecting the more specific overload however, but calling back into itself. It clearly has something to do with the base type being generic, but I don't understand why it wouldn't select the Execute(string) overload.

Does anyone have any insight into this?

*The above code was simplified to show the pattern, the actual structure is a bit more complicated, but the issue is the same.*

Comment: Not really sure of the spec which determines method resolution, but a workaround for the time being would be `((Executor<string>)this).Execute((string)item)`.. Which is *extremely* ugly.

Comment: According to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32892243/which-c-sharp-method-overload-is-chosen) the most specific overload should be chosen.

Comment: @Steve that is not the same scenario as what is presented here since that doesn't deal with overriding and the C# spec specifically deals with this particular case differently.

Comment: @DavidL so it seems. I wasn't aware, very interesting.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Looks like this is mentioned in the C# specification 5.0, 7.5.3 Overload Resolution:

> Overload resolution selects the function member to invoke in the following distinct contexts within C#:
>
> - Invocation of a method named in an invocation-expression (§7.6.5.1).
> - Invocation of an instance constructor named in an    object-creation-expression (§7.6.10.1).
> - Invocation of an indexer accessor through an element-access (§7.6.6).
> - Invocation of a predefined or user-defined operator referenced in an    expression (§7.3.3 and §7.3.4).
>
> Each of these contexts defines the set of candidate function members
>   and the list of arguments in its own unique way, as described in
>   detail in the sections listed above. For example, the set of
>   candidates for a method invocation **does not include methods marked
>   override (§7.4), and methods in a base class are not candidates if any
>   method in a derived class is applicable** (§7.6.5.1).

When we look at 7.4:

> A member lookup of a name N with K type parameters in a type T is processed as follows:
>
> • First, a set of accessible members named N is determined:
>
> - If T is a type parameter, then the set is the union of the sets of
>     accessible members named N in each of the types specified as a primary constraint or secondary constraint (§10.1.5) for T, along with the set of accessible members named N in object.
> - Otherwise, the set consists of all accessible (§3.5) members named N in T, including inherited members and the accessible membersnamed N in object. If T is a constructed type, the set of members
>     is obtained    by substituting type arguments as described in §10.3.2.
>     **Members that    include an override modifier are excluded from the set.**

If you remove `override` the compiler picks the `Execute(string)` overload when you cast the item.

Comment: Of course my follow up question would be: why? I'm sure there is a good reason, but this seems like surprising behavior to me.

Comment: @Mark Jon Skeet's [article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx) describes the reason, "The reason for this is to reduce the risk of the brittle base class problem, where the introduction of a new method to a base class could cause problems for consumers of classes derived from it."

Comment: @khargoosh Skeet's explanation deals with a different problem (why a method in the parent class is ignored even if it were a better fit). The brittle base class problem clearly can't apply here, since we are dealing with a function added to the child class not the base class. Changing the behavior to also consider overriden methods in the same class, would not change the behavior when adding a method to the base class at all (which is what the fragile base class problem deals with).

Comment: Jon actually goes on and points out the problem mentioned here afterwards but doesn't mention any reason and calls the behavior "particularly surprising" himself.

Comment: @Voo: It is possibly surprising, but again, by design. See my answer.

Comment: Something good I find about this design is that `this.Execute` implies recursion into the override defined in "`this`" class, and `base.Execute` or `((Executor<T>)this).Execute` (with an explicit type for `T`)  is required to call a less-local implementation.
*TL;DR*: A call to the base implementation is less likely to be intended, so it requires a more explicit statement. The more implicit statement results in what's (in my opinion) more likely intended.

Answer (score 24):

As mentioned in Jon Skeet's [article on overloading](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx), when invoking a method in a class that also overrides a method with the same name from a base class, the compiler will always take the in-class method instead of the override, regardless of the "specificness" of type, provided that the signature is "compatible".

Jon goes on to point out that this is an excellent argument for avoiding overloading across inheritance boundaries, since this is exactly the kind of unexpected behavior that can occur.

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't have anything to do with the generic base class. I can repro without that aspect to the code. This was very surprising to me.

Comment: Correct, the generic parameter is a red herring in this scenario.

Comment: @Mark: There *are* ways to construct overload resolution problems in which the genericity or lack thereof is used as a tiebreaker, but this is not one of them. For example, given `class C { void M(int){} void M<T>(T){} }` and a call to `c.M(123)`, the non-generic will win. And there are more subtle tiebreakers than even that; see the specification for details.

Answer (score 17):

As other answers have noted, this is by design.

Let's consider a less complicated example:

```
class Animal
{
  public virtual void Eat(Apple a) { ... }
}
class Giraffe : Animal
{
  public void Eat(Food f) { ... }
  public override void Eat(Apple a) { ... }
}
```

The question is why `giraffe.Eat(apple)` resolves to `Giraffe.Eat(Food)` and not the virtual `Animal.Eat(Apple)`.

This is a consequence of two rules:

(1) The type of the receiver is more important than the type of any argument when resolving overloads.

I hope it is clear why this must be the case. The person writing the derived class has strictly more knowledge than the person writing the base class, because the person writing the derived class used the base class, and not vice versa.

The person who wrote `Giraffe` said "I have a way for a `Giraffe` to eat *any food*" and that requires special knowledge of the internals of giraffe digestion. That information is not present in the base class implementation, which only knows how to eat apples.

So overload resolution should always prioritize choosing an applicable method of a derived class over choosing a method of a base class, *regardless of the betterness of the argument type conversions.*

(2) Choosing to override or not override a virtual method is not part of the public surface area of a class. That's a private implementation detail.  Therefore no decision must be made when doing overload resolution that would change depending on whether or not a method is overridden.

Overload resolution must never say "I'm going to choose virtual `Animal.Eat(Apple)` *because it was overridden*".

Now, you might well say "OK, suppose I am *inside* Giraffe when I am making the call."  Code *inside* Giraffe has all the knowledge of private implementation details, right? So it could make the decision to call virtual `Animal.Eat(Apple)` instead of `Giraffe.Eat(Food)` when faced with `giraffe.Eat(apple)`, right? Because it knows that there is an implementation that understands the needs of giraffes that eat apples.

That's a cure worse than the disease.  Now we have a situation where *identical* code has *different* behaviour depending on where it is run!  You can imagine having a call to `giraffe.Eat(apple)` outside of the class, refactor it so that it is inside of the class, and suddenly observable behaviour changes!

Or, you might say, hey, I realize that my Giraffe logic is actually sufficiently general to move to a base class, but not to Animal, so I am going to refactor my `Giraffe` code to:

```
class Mammal : Animal 
{
  public void Eat(Food f) { ... } 
  public override void Eat(Apple a) { ... }
}
class Giraffe : Mammal
{
  ...
}
```

And now all calls to `giraffe.Eat(apple)` *inside* `Giraffe` suddenly have *different* overload resolution behaviour after the refactoring?  That would be very unexpected!

C# is a pit-of-success language; we want very much to make sure that simple refactorings like changing where in a hierarchy a method is overridden do not cause subtle changes in behaviour.

Summing up:

- Overload resolution prioritizes receivers over other arguments because calling specialized code that knows the internals of the receiver is better than calling more general code that does not.
- Whether and where a method is overridden is not considered during overload resolution; all methods are treated as though they were *never* overridden for purposes of overload resolution. It's an implementation detail, not part of the surface of the type.
- Overload resolution problems are solved -- modulo accessibility of course! -- the same way no matter where the problem occurs in the code. We do not have one algorithm for resolution where the receiver is of the type of the containing code, and another for when the call is in a different class.

Additional thoughts on related issues can be found here: https://ericlippert.com/2013/12/23/closer-is-better/ and here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/09/04/future-breaking-changes-part-three/