# Why is the compiler choosing the generic method over specific one?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have this service interface.

```
public interface IService
{
    Task SetAsync(string key, string value, TimeSpan? expiration = null);
    Task SetAsync<T>(string applicationName, string key, T value, TimeSpan? expiration = null);
}
```

I would like to call the first method by doing so.

```
service.SetAsync("Key", "Value", TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
```

The method call matches 100% the contract of the first method. Yet the compiler chooses the second method by assuming `TimeSpan` is my generic type.

Why is this happening?

Comment: It's having defaults for the later parameters that throws things off. I'll try to find an apt duplicate

Comment: An easy workaround to run other method is to specify its parameter name explicitly: `service.SetAsync(key:"Key", "Value", TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));` ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IsNvVm))

Comment: Try ```new Service().SetAsync("Key", "Value", new TimeSpan?());``` .  Cause ```TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)``` is ```TimeSpan``` not ```TimeSpan?```

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I would expect not requiring the default parameter to make the *first* method preferable. Investigating...

Comment: If you pass a non null then it take first method or replace the ```TimeSpan?``` to ```TimeSpan``` on your method it will take first method too.

Comment: @MichaelMao: I don't follow what you're saying. The OP is already passing a non-null value, but the compiler is apparently choosing the *second* method, not the first as you expect.

Comment: But I *believe* it's the requirement to use an implicit conversion which causes the second method to be "better". Currently looking up chapter and verse in the ECMA standard...

Comment: Some reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32892243/which-c-sharp-method-overload-is-chosen

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is following the rules for "Better function member" in the ECMA C# 5 standard, section 12.6.4.3:

> For the purposes of determining the better function member, a stripped-down argument list A is constructed containing just the argument expressions themselves in the order they appear in the original argument list.
>
> Parameter lists for each of the candidate function members are constructed in the following way:
>
> - The expanded form is used if the function member was applicable only in the expanded form.
> - Optional parameters with no corresponding arguments are removed from the parameter list
> - The parameters are reordered so that they occur at the same position as the corresponding argument in the argument list.

So at that point, we're comparing these two methods, effectively:

```cs
Task SetAsync(string key, string value, TimeSpan? expiration);
Task SetAsync<T>(string applicationName, string key, T value);
```

(In the generic method version, the `expiration` parameter does not have a corresponding argument, so it's removed from the parameter list.)

The argument list is `"Key", "Value", TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)`, and `T` is inferred to be `TimeSpan`.

Next:

> Given an argument list A with a set of argument expressions { E1, E2, ..., EN } and two applicable function members MP and MQ with parameter types { P1, P2, ..., PN } and { Q1, Q2, ..., QN }, MP is defined to be a better function member than MQ if
>
> - for each argument, the implicit conversion from EX to QX is not better than the implicit conversion from EX to PX, and
> - for at least one argument, the conversion from EX to PX is better than the conversion from EX to QX.

For the first two parameters, there's no difference - because they're `string` everywhere.

For the third parameter, the conversion for the non-generic method is from `TimeSpan` to `TimeSpan?`, and for the generic method it's from `TimeSpan` to `TimeSpan` (because `T` is `TimeSpan`).

The identity conversion of `TimeSpan` to `TimeSpan` is "better" (as per the rules of 12.6.4.4) than the implicit conversion of `TimeSpan` to `TimeSpan?`, so for that parameter, the generic method is "better"... and there's no parameter for which the non-generic method is "better", therefore overall the generic method is better.

If neither method had been found to be "better" in this stage (e.g. due to a parameter type of `TimeSpan` instead of `TimeSpan?` for the optional parameter) then the non-generic method would have been determined to be "better" by the tie-break rules following this stage. But by that point, the generic method has already been selected.

Comment: A-ha, following the rules, it all makes sense now. Thank you for clearing this up. I would be lying if I said this didn't lose me an hour of sleep last night. It's especially the rules of 12.6.4.4 that make this easy confusable. My gut feeling tells me I would have to specify `<TimeSpan>` to make the compiler choose the generic method. But that's where 12.6.4.4 comes in.