# C# (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), param) calls parameterless constructor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, activator

HexMap is an object created by Unity game engine. MonoBehaviour is base Unity class. Problem occurs when passing this object as a parameter.

```
public class HexMap : MonoBehaviour
{

}

public class A
{
    public A(){}
    public A(HexMap hexMap)
    {
    }
}
    
public class B : A
{
    public B(){}
    public B(HexMap hexMap) : base(hexMap)
    {
    }
}

// This object is created by Unity and found successfully
HexMap hexMap = Object.FindObjectOfType<HexMap>();
A a = (A)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(B), hexMap);
```

Code above calls B parameterless constructor. How to make it call a constructor with a parameter?

Comment: What dio you pass as `param`?

Comment: It worked as expect for me too, even setting `param` to `null`.

Comment: Is the constructor perhaps not public in your actual code?

Comment: @KlausGütter I passed "HexMap : Monobehaviour" object (Unity)

Comment: Why not just do `var a = new B(hexMap);`.  Why the need for _reflection?_  You want to avoid that at the best of times in games due to the performance hit,

Comment: @MickyD because the actual code is: 
A a = (A)Activator.CreateInstance(unit.GetType(), hexMap);
while I don't know unit's type

Comment: I think you should rethink your design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the edits and providing your actual code I can tell you what the issue is - it is quite a tricky pitfall!

There are various overloads of [`Activator.CreateInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance). In specific

- one that takes [`(Type, params Object?[]?)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance#system-activator-createinstance(system-type-system-object())), the one you are wanting to use here.
- **However**, there is also another one that takes [`(Type, bool)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance#system-activator-createinstance(system-type-system-boolean))

Now what is tricking you here is that [`UnityEngine.Object`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.html) (which [`MonoBehaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html) and basically all built-in class types derive from) has an [implicit conversion operator to `bool`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_Object.html) (also see [source code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/3f0dae724475e51dab2c924c4fa470cfd0269280/Runtime/Export/Scripting/UnityEngineObject.bindings.cs#L98)) so the compiler is treating your `hexMap` as a `bool` parameter and therefore prefers the second overload which is a parameterless constructor. See also [Which Method overload is chosen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32892243/which-c-sharp-method-overload-is-chosen) for more details on the reasons.

To make clear for the compiler what you want to do you rather want to explicitely pass in

```
A a = (A)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(B), new object[]{hexMap});
```

Little simulation of the issue: https://dotnetfiddle.net/x0YqYs