# Why is this not an ambiguous call?

Tags: c#

Out of curiosity, why is `Log(null)` not an ambiguous call in this scenario?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Log(null); // Output is "String"
    }

    static void Log(object value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Object");
    }

    static void Log(string value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("String");
    }
}
```

As both `Log(object)` and `Log(string)` accepts `null` as parameter I was expecting the compiler to give me an ambiguous call error, but instead it chooses to call `Log(string)`. Why not `Log(object)`?

Comment: This may have already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9017396/2704659

Comment: I agree with Alex K. that this is a duplicate. If you think it is not, please let us know.